# Getting mutable references out of slices

Tags: rust

I have a trait with the following functions:

```rust
pub trait MappedMemory {
    fn range(&self) -> MappedMemoryRange;
    
    fn flush(&mut self);
    fn flush_range(&mut self, range: MappedMemoryRange);
    fn flush_ranges(&mut self, ranges: &[MappedMemoryRange]);
    
    fn flush_multiple(memories: &[&mut Self]);
    fn flush_multiple_ranges(memories: &[(&mut Self, MappedMemoryRange)]);
}

pub struct MappedMemoryRange {
    pub offset: u64,
    pub size: usize
}
```

And I'm trying to provide a default implementation for `flush_multiple` that calls `flush_multiple_ranges`.

I tried something like this to convert the `&[&mut Self]` to a `&[(&mut Self, MappedMemoryRange)]`:

```rust
let memories_and_ranges: Vec<(&mut Self, MappedMemoryRange)> = memories
    .into_iter()
    .map(|m| (*m, m.range()))
    .collect();
```

This gives me errors though:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*m` which is behind a shared reference
  --> crates\xyz\src\objects\memory.rs:44:23
   |
44 |             .map(|m| (*m, m.range()))
   |                       ^^ move occurs because `*m` has type `&mut Self`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I convince rust that I'm just passing these references along, similar to how I would do it if I had a single reference?

Comment: You cannot mutate through a `&mut Self` if it's behind a shared reference (`&[&mut Self]`) so this might not be the best choice of signature anyways.

Comment: But to answer your question "How can I convince rust that I'm just passing these references along?": by taking ownership of them.

Comment: Suggestions for better signatures are also welcome if that solves the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do so the best I can do is guess. Usually you'd want something like `&mut [&mut Self]` if you need mutable access to a bunch of `Self`s. Or take ownership of the references with `Vec<&mut Self>`. Or take `&[&Self]` if you don't actually need to mutate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental misunderstanding in my question came down to this: `&mut T` does not mean mutable reference, and more importantly `&T` does not mean immutable reference. Instead `&mut T` is a unique reference, and `&T` is a shared reference. `&T` can still be mutable using interior mutability.

In this specific case, I should be using `&[&Self]` since the references need to be shared. As long as the flush call releases the mutable interior before returning everything should be fine. Also, `MappedMemory` is not `Sync`, so I don't need to think about concurrent access either.

Apparently there was a big discussion in the early days of rust about `mut` being called `mut` instead of something like `uniq`, which was part of the "mutpocalypse". Sadly nothing came out of it, because I certainly had the wrong understanding for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mutate a mutable reference behind an immutable reference. The function signature has to be:

```rust
fn flush_multiple(memories: &mut [&mut Self])
```

And it can be implemented like:

```rust
let memories_and_ranges: Vec<(MappedMemoryRange, &mut Self)> = memories
    .iter_mut()
    .map(|m| (m.range(), &mut **m))
    .collect();
```

I swapped the order (`MappedMemoryRange` first) since with the previous order you're borrowing `m` for `m.range()` while it is already borrowed mutably.

However, it is not clear to me why you don't just call `flush()` on each memory, without calculating its range.

Comment: m is of type `&mut self`. right ? where `self` is `MappedMemory`. Didn't get why you did `&mut **m`,

Comment: @kumarmo2 No, `m` is of type `&mut &mut Self`, one because of the slice type and the other because mutable iterators over slices yield `&mut T`.

Comment: oh ok. i missed the slice. Thanks